# I am using a bag house filter to filter particulates in cement industry. suggest an economical combined technology to filter the gases as well

Tags: environmental-engineering, air

I have designed the baghouse filter but I don't know what device should I install in combination with the baghouse such that it filters the toxic gases too. I saw a lot of technologies but the cost is creating issues. Can anyone pls suggest an economical option. Plus it would be great if someone explains its orientation aswell (where to install it).

Comment: You probably need activated charcoal or carbon. Toxic gasses is quite vague though and being more specific would let you target the gasses you're trying to remove. This won't make things cheaper though since it's usually "activated carbon" or "something different that only targets a more specific gas and also costs more because activated carbon won't work"

Comment: "Toxic gases" isn't very meaningful.  What gases do you need to remove?

Comment: You cannot filter a gas.  Filtration is a mechanical process.  You have to capture gasses via chemical reaction.

Comment: NOx, SOx and CO are the effluent gasses I'm dealing with.

Comment: All those become acids in water, so I wonder if some kind of aquaeous acid-base chemistry (like to eventually to turn them into a salt) or capture into water on a moist surface, that would be the way to go? Seems like there would be tons of literature on this, since limiting these is a nearly universal requirement for power plants - albeit at room temp the winning solution might be totally different vs combustion exhaust

Comment: yes there is lots of literature, I wanted some new ideas to work and research on. some technology that can filter all the gases at once.

Comment: New ideas and economical tend to be on opposite sides of the scale, even if it is only due to the economy running the old methods at large scales.

Comment: I have now planned to integrate adsorption (looking for suitable adsorbent) with the baghouse filter. This way I won't have to design an extra setup. I understand this requires experimentation but sticking to research at the moment. Am I in the right direction? If anyone has prior experience, please help me out.

Comment: So what chemicals are those particular gasses absorbed by?